# PHP - fread() waiting until another fwrite() script ends

Tags: php, fopen, freeze, fwrite, fread

### Update

As [this.lau_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561309/this-lau) commented, it seems the problem is that no code is running at all on the server when the first file is running. I guess some configuration only allows one script to be run at once - or only one script per "user".

Now I will investigate what can be causing that behaviour on the server. Thank you everyone for your help!

.

### Original question

I've got two PHP scripts, on separate files:

```
/* The first file contains */
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){
    $w = fopen($progress_file, "w");
    fwrite($w, $i);
    fclose($w);
}

/* The second file contains */
$f = fopen($progress_file, "r");
$progress_read = fread($f, filesize($progress_file));
fclose($f);
echo $progress_read !== false ? $progress_read : 0;
```

As you can see, I make a loop so I have time to refresh second file and wait for it to give the the number it's written in that moment.

I know that, when doing `fopen($file, "w");` I'm truncating that file, so it won't give me (sometimes) the number it should give, and it will give 0. However, **it should echo something**, as I check if the file has been able to be read and, otherwise, echo "0".

Instead, I get the second file waiting (shown as loading) without echoing nothing until the first file gets completed the whole loop (so I always end up with "9999" on the second file).

I've tried changing the modes of `fopen()` with no luck, as well as making the `fopen()` and `fclose()` outside the loop. No luck neither. I've also tried changing the fopen-fread-fclose thing with `file_get_contents()` and other functions and nothing has worked.

Also, `fflush()`, `ob_flush()` and `flush()` haven't made any difference.

As I said, the file gets written (if I open it with a text editor, I see the content changes) and even if it wouldn't, it should echo "0".

**Why is the second file waiting, without echoing nothing, until the first loop ends?**

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly the file is being accessed by the first file and the second has to wait until the first has release access.  I am not 100% sure but maybe.

Comment: Also if you are only running the loop to allow a refresh time then may I suggest `sleep()` - http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_sleep.asp

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve. The second php file can run only during the short time between `fclose` and `fopen` in the first php file so maybe that's simply not enough time. Or maybe the system simply optimizes that by leaving the file open. Maybe try to put `sleep(5)` after fclose to check.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. The `sleep(5);` seems not to be the answer, as I get the same result: the first page is loading forever (it's ok) but so does the second script, which even refreshing it every 3 seconds (so I get any chance of hitting that 5 seconds rest) gets no answer. It's still frozen. 

And I would like to ask: why the second file can only run between fclose and fopen? If I run `fopen()` in read mode, then it should open the file no matter if it's being written. Thank you again.

Comment: Are you sure that any code is actually running in the second file? Maybe try to put just `echo "test"` in there to double-check. Maybe with your current setup only one php can run at a time so the second one is waiting for the first one to finish, independently of any file locking.

Comment: @this.lau_ you're right. No code is running on the second file, even writing a simple `echo "hello"; exit;` does not work. Why can it be that? Maybe a server configuration? I'm running on IIS 7. Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no simple answer, but you should definitely try semaphores, available in PHP5.6 http://php.net/manual/es/book.sem.php Otherwise, you could implement this kind of semaphores on your own

Answer (score 0):

So for the use of for loops in PHP you must know it will do the thing in the loop till the condition in the for loop is false. So taken your code the forloop wil at first run take:

```
for(i=0; i<1000; i++){...}
```

And this returns true so it go in the forloop and execute every thing you want. At the end it will execute i++ en will go back to the evaluation of the for loop so :

```
for(i=1 i<1000; i++){...}
```

and again this is true. Well this go on till i = 9999. So in the meanwhile it opend and closed the file 9999 times en wrote the correspondence number in this file. As you hopefully can see is that your code is locked at that forloop and wont continue to go further than when the forloop is evaluated false.

You can make this work is you make you forloop like it is now but when you close the file in the forloop you call a method from the other file like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){
    $w = fopen($progress_file, "w");
    fwrite($w, $i);
    fclose($w);
    doSomthingWithFile($filename);
}
```

And on the other side:

```
doSomthingWithFile($filename){
    $f = fopen($filename, "r");
    $progress_read = fread($f, filesize($filename));
    fclose($f);
    echo $progress_read !== false ? $progress_read : 0;
}
```

I hope this make somethings clear.

Comment: Although this may work, I think the comment of @this.lau_ gets more sense. Even if this would be the right way to do so, I cannot because both files get called by different AJAX calls, so I cannot call one file from within the other, and getting the AJAX response parsing would be much more complicated. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: In the case of AJAX call parsing it will be more complicated. No sweat glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The second script does not wait. You either need to use

```
file_put_contents($filename,$str,LOCK_EX);
```

to force files waiting or you need to implement some loop with delay.

You could add a loop on the begin of your script to start test at same time like this:

```
echo "flock test ".time()."<br>";
$constant_time = 1570612500;
while ( time()<$constant_time )
{
usleep(500);
}
```

Where $constant_time is time when you wish to start both scripts in the same time. Give it current time shown by echo + 20 seconds, then upload it on server, then run the scripts (you need to do that before the time elapsed. This way both scripts will start at the same time.

PS: I originally searched answer if fread can wait when LOC_EX is set and this question came out.